# GROUP BY without the key in the resulting bag

Tags: apache-pig

I have:

```
a b 
a c 
a d
```

and I would like to generate:

```
a, {(b),(c),(d)}
```

Doing this by using `GROUP` results in:

```
a, {(a,b),(a,c),(a,d)}
```

How do I get rid of the first field in the bag?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

There is no option to do this in `GROUP`. You'll have to project that column out in a `FOREACH`.

```
-- DESCRIBE A ;
-- A: {c1: chararray, c2: chararray}
-- DUMP A ;
-- a b
-- a c
-- a d

B = GROUP A BY c1 ;
C = FOREACH B GENERATE group AS c1, A.c2 AS grpd_c2 ;
```

In cases where I have to do this I generally use this way for brevity:

```
D = FOREACH (GROUP A BY c1)
    GENERATE group AS c1, A.c2 AS grpd_c2 ;
```

(Also, this way helps to remind me to **not** to use `B.c2`)

The key is `A.c2` which returns a bag with only the `c2` column from the original bag. If, for example, you had 3 fields (`c1`, `c2`, `c3`) you would use `A.(c2, c3)` instead.

Answer (score 1):

B = GROUP A BY c1 ;

If you have more fields, it will be something like this:

C = FOREACH B GENERATE group AS c1, A.(c2,....);